# TMC222 Stepper Controller, motor busy function

Tags: python

I am currently working on a robot that has to traverse a maze.
For the robot I am using a TMC222 Stepper controller and the software is coded in Python.

I am in need of a function which can tell me when the motors are busy so that the robot will seize all other activity while the motors are running.

My idea is to check the current position on the motors and compare it to the target position, but i haven't gotten it to work yet.

My current attempt:

```
        def isRunning(self):
        print("IS RUNNING TEST")

        fullstatus=self.getFullStatus2()

        #print("FULL STATUS: " + str(fullstatus[0]) + " 2 " + str(fullstatus[1]))

        actLeft=fullstatus[0][1]<<8 | fullstatus[0][2]<<0
        actRight=fullstatus[1][1]<<8 | fullstatus[1][2]<<0

        tarLeft=fullstatus[0][3]<<8 | fullstatus[0][4]<<0
        tarRight=fullstatus[1][3]<<8 | fullstatus[1][4]<<0

        value = (actLeft==tarLeft) and (actRight==tarRight)

        value = not value
#       print("isbusy="+str(value))
        print 'ActPos = ' + str(actLeft)
        print 'TarPos = ' + str(tarLeft)

        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your `getFullStatus2()` code as well, since it's unclear to me how you're getting a multidimensional output.

In general, you can form a 16-bit "word" from two 8-bit bytes just as you have it:

```
Word = HB << 8 | LB << 0
```

Where HB and LB are the high (bits 15-8) and low (bits 7-0) bytes.

That being said, there are multiple ways to detect motor stall.  The ideal way would be an external pressure switch that closed when it  hit a wall.  Another would be to monitor the motor's current, when the motor faces resistance (when accelerating or in stall), the current will rise.

Since it looks like neither of these are possible, I'd use still a different approach, monitoring the motor's position (presumably from some sort of encoder) over time.

Lets say you have a function `get_position()` that returns an unsigned 16-bit integer.  You should be able to write something like:

```
class MotorPosition(object):
    def __init__(self):
        readings = []

    def poll(self):
        p = get_position()
        self.readings.append(readings)

        # If the list is now too long, remove the oldest entries
        if len(self.readings) > 5:
            self.readings.pop(0)

    def get_deltas():
        deltas = []
        for x,y in zip(self.readings[1:4], self.readings[0:3]):
            d = x - y
            # Wraparound detection
            if  (d < -THRESHOLD): d += 65536
            elif(d >  THRESHOLD): d -= 65536
            deltas.append(d)
       return deltas

    def get_average_delta():
        deltas = self.get_deltas()
        return sum(deltas) / float(len(deltas))
```

Note that this assumes you're polling the encoder fast enough and with consistent frequency.

You could then monitor the average delta (from `get_average_delta()`) and if it drops below some value, you consider the motor stalled.

Assumptions:

- [This](http://www.avrcard.com/Documents/datasheets/tmc222_datasheet_v105.pdf) is the datasheet for the controller you're using
- Your I²C code is working correctly